# save row value when I select the checkbox

Tags: php, jquery, html-table

I apologize for my bad English, I hope I can explain myself better.

1. Json file: through this code the call is made to view the contents of the file:

```
<? php
$ login = 'XL8T7924H9G9U1M99GTSVV9BHC2KYRFL';
$ password = '';
$ url = 'https://www.website.com/api/products?&output_format=JSON&display=full';
$ ch = curl_init ();
curl_setopt ($ ch, CURLOPT_URL, $ url);
curl_setopt ($ ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($ ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt ($ ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$ login: $ password");
$ result = curl_exec ($ ch);
curl_close ($ ch);
$ json = json_decode ($ result, true);
/ echo ($ result);
?>
```

2. results are shown with datatable this code

```
<form action = "" method = "post">
<table id = "example" class = "table table-striped table-bordered zero-configuration">
<thead>
<tr>
<th class = "th-sm"> # </th>
<th class = "th-sm"> Name </th>
<th class = "th-sm"> Description </th>
<th class = "th-sm"> Short Description </th>
<th class = "th-sm"> Image </th>
<th class = "th-sm"> Activate </th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<div class = "form-group" style = "text-align: -webkit-center;">
<div class = "form-check form-check-inline">
<? php
foreach ($ json ['products'] as $ data)
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>". $ data ['id']. "</td>";
echo "<td>". $ data ['name']. "</td>";
echo "<td>". $ data ['description']. "</td>";
echo "<td>". $ data ['description_short']. "</td>";
echo "<td>". '<img src = "http://www.website.com/'.$data [" id_default_image "] .'- home_default /'.$ data [" link_rewrite "].'. jpg" class = "img-thumbnail "width =" 120 "height =" auto "/> ';
echo "<td> <input type = 'checkbox' name = 'checkbox' value = '1'> </td>";
echo "</tr>";
}?>
</tbody>
</table>
<input type = "submit" name = "submitp" id = "submitp" value = "submit">
</form>
```

3. through a checkbox and submit I can save the information on a txt file this is the code

```
<? php
if (isset ($ _ POST ['submitp'])) {
$ id = "product id:". $ _ POST ['id']. "";
$ name = "product name:". $ _ POST ['name']. "";
$ description = "product description:". $ _ POST ['description']. "";
$ description_short = "short product description:". $ _ POST ['description_short']. "";
$ image = "product image:". $ _ POST ['image']. "";
$ file = fopen ("file.txt", "w +");
fwrite ($ file, $ id);
fwrite ($ file, $ name);
fwrite ($ file, $ description);
fwrite ($ file, $ short_description);
fwrite ($ file, $ image);
fclose ($ file);
}
?>
```

I know I'm wrong but I can't figure out how to save the entire selected row.

what you want to achieve: saving the selected row with its id, name, description and short description through the checkbox

errors: none

what it saves: only the contents of the checkbox

I hope I have explained myself well and thank you for your help

Comment: That PHP code will trigger tons of syntax errors. What have you tried to resolve them?

Comment: These blankspaces, worse than a wordpress source :D `"w +"`, `$ _ POST ['description']`, remove all these blankspaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only form fields are submitted to the server. The table cells without a field will not be sent on submission

You can have a set of hidden fields populated by JavaScript when you check the box, (see later)

Alternatively you could use AJAX

You have checkboxes, do you want to save more than one row? If not, use radios instead

Change

```
   echo "<td>". $data ['id']. "</td>";
   echo "<td>". $data ['name']. "</td>";
   echo "<td>". $data ['description']. "</td>";
   echo "<td>". $data ['description_short']. "</td>";
```

to

```
   echo "<td data-key=\"id\">". $data ['id']. "</td>";
   echo "<td data-key=\"name\">". $data ['name']. "</td>";
   echo "<td data-key=\"description\">". $data ['description']. "</td>";
   echo "<td data-key=\"description_short\">". $data ['description_short']. "</td>";
   echo "<td data-key=\"image\">". '<img src = "http://www.website.com/'.$data [" id_default_image "] .'- home_default /'.$ data [" link_rewrite "].'. jpg" class = "img-thumbnail "width =" 120 "height =" auto "/> ';
```

Then use

```
$(function() {
  $("form").on("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // stop submission
    let details = $('input[name="checkbox"]:checked')
      .closest("tr") // parent row
      .find("td[data-key]") // only the ones with a key attribute
      .map(function() {
        return {
          [this.dataset.key]: this.textContent.trim() || $(this).find("img").attr("src")
        }
      })
      .get();
    console.log(details);
    if (details) {
      $.post("https://plungjan.name/SO/phponerow/save.php", JSON.stringify(details), function(data) {
        console.log("Details saved", data)
      })
    }
  })
})
```

```js
$(function() {
  $("form").on("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // stop submission
    let details = $('input[name="checkbox"]:checked')
      .closest("tr") // parent row
      .find("td[data-key]") // only the ones with a key attribute
      .map(function() {
        return {
          [this.dataset.key]: this.textContent.trim() || $(this).find("img").attr("src")
        }
      })
      .get();
    console.log(details);
    if (details) {
      $.post("https://plungjan.name/SO/phponerow/save.php", JSON.stringify(details), function(data) {
        console.log("Details saved", data)
      })
    }
  })
})


My PHP is 

<?php 

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
// $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
echo $data;
?>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td data-key="id">ID 1</td>
        <td data-key="name">Name 1</td>
        <td data-key="description">Description 1 </td>
        <td data-key="description_short">Short 1</td>
        <td data-key="image"><img src="http://www.website.com/id_default_image/home_default/link_rewrite1.jpg" class="img-thumbnail" width="120" height="auto" />
          <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td data-key="id">ID 2</td>
        <td data-key="name">Name 2</td>
        <td data-key="description">Description 2 </td>
        <td data-key="description_short">Short 2</td>
        <td data-key="image"><img src="http://www.website.com/id_default_image/home_default/link_rewrite2.jpg" class="img-thumbnail" width="120" height="auto" />
          <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td data-key="id">ID 3</td>
        <td data-key="name">Name 3</td>
        <td data-key="description">Description 3 </td>
        <td data-key="description_short">Short 3</td>
        <td data-key="image"><img src="http://www.website.com/id_default_image/home_default/link_rewrite3.jpg" class="img-thumbnail" width="120" height="auto" />
          <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" /></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

---

Using hidden fields for ONE checked box (same data attributes as above):

```
<form>
   <input type="hidden" name="id">
   <input type="hidden" name="name">
   <input type="hidden" name="description">
   <input type="hidden" name="description_short">
   <input type="hidden" name="image" />
```

using

```
$(function() {
  $("form").on("submit",function(e) {
    const form = this; // save the form
    $('input[name="checkbox"]:checked')
      .closest("tr") / parent row
      .find("td[key]") // only the ones with a key attribute
      .each(function() {
        form[key].value = this.textContent || $(this).find(img).attr("src");
      })    
  })
})
```

Comment: thanks for your kind reply, i can't save the whole line info once checkbox is checked on my txt file, i used this syntax
   $ (function () {
     $ ("form"). on ("submitp", function (e) {
       e.preventDefault ();
       let details = $ ('input [name = "checkbox"]: checked')
         .closest ("tr")
         .find ("td [key]")
         .map (function () {return {[this.dataset.key]: this.textContent})
         .get ();
       $ .post ("MySaveUrl.php", details, function () {alert ("Details saved");})
     })
   })
});
the MySaveUrl.php file contains the information as in point 3

Comment: unfortunately my bad english and google translator doesn't help me much, could she connect to my pc with anydesk?

Comment: thanks, I have to save everything on a txt file or a json file

Comment: @Luigi I have updated the answer with a working example

Comment: ok, you have been very kind to dedicate yourself to my problem, but I can't understand why if I select the product with id 5 for example, I only see the product with id 10, it was up to me I would send you my files by email

Comment: Ok, my contact details are in my profile

Answer (score 0):

When you submit, it only submits`input`s (and a couple of other input types, like `select`, `textarea`).

`<td>123</td>` will not be submitted.

You can add *hidden* inputs, built and populated at the same time as your build your table, which will then also be submitted, eg:

```
<td>123<input type='hidden' name='id[0]' value='123'></td>
```

You'll need to use the correct format for `name=id[0]` to ensure php picks up all the rows in different values; there's different ways to do this.

The essential part of this question/answer is to include a hidden input.

Comment: sorry I did not understand